# dataset property doesn't work with objects?

Tags: javascript, object

```
el2.dataset.stuff = document.getElementById('el1');
```

doesn't seem to work.

I need to be able to access the innerHTML property of el1, later.

```
el2.dataset.stuff = document.getElementById('el1').innerHTML;
```

works, but I don't like the idea of storing duplicate content in variables. If I have many elements, it would eat up a lot of memory.

I guess because dataset requires strings? If that's true, how do I set reference to another elmement inside el2 ?

Comment: You could just put the id of the element you want it to store.

Comment: In my code, I don't really have an ID. this is just an example.. I do have the index of the element though..

Comment: It works with objects in the sense that you can serialize and deserialize them (with something like `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`), but that's not possible with DOM elements, so no, you can't store them.

Comment: As a note, jQuery has the `.data()` method that does what you want and would work perfect for your situation...if you're using jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you just can store strings in `dataset` attributes by definition.

So in your case either you should have a separate data-structure (which should be accessible in both needed scopes) to store your reference like this:

```
var myPointers = {
  'el2': {
    'stuff': document.getElementById('el1')
  }
};

// later

var el1 = myPointers.el2.stuff;
```

Or you just store the id of `el1` and retrieve the actual element, when it is needed:

```
el2.dataset.stuff = 'el1';

// later 

var el1 = document.getElementById( el2.dataset.stuff );
```

Comment: thanks, but I added it as a property of el2 like el2.stuff = document.getElementById('el1'). Seems to work :D

Comment: @AnnaK. With your solution you are appending something to the DOM object, while `dataset` additionally would have added something to the actual HTML element. As long as your identifier `stuff` is not used by some other functionality, you will be fine. But in case some plugin or browser uses that term, you will run into problems.

Comment: Looks like this might become useful for building web components.